# Inline Assembly with GCC

Tags: c++, assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
get_random(void)
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
        "mov eax, 42           \n");
    asm("mov eax, 42 \n");
}
int
main(void)
{
    return printf("The answer is %d.\n", get_random());
}
```

I am trying to compile this C++ program with these CLI commands:
`g++ asm.cpp -o asm`

Error messages:

```
/tmp/ccXHbaRO.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccXHbaRO.s:41: Error: no such instruction: `movl %eax,%esi'
/tmp/ccXHbaRO.s:42: Error: no such instruction: `movl $.LC0,%edi'
/tmp/ccXHbaRO.s:43: Error: no such instruction: `movl $0,%eax'
```

Because I added `asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n");` I thought I wouldn't need to add the GCC flag `-masm=intel`?

Also, where can I find out more information about the `-masm` flag? Is there a NASM equivalent?

Comment: Did you try `%eax%` `%esi%` using the `%` symbols your source code doesn't have any `%` this is AT&T assembly not Intel assembly

Comment: @SSpoke I want to use the Intel Syntax. Which is why I added the line `asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n");`.

Comment: try replacing it with `".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"` use `".att_syntax prefix"` as the last line might work, Honestly the best way to fix your problem is to use Intel to AT&T Assembly converter which works just fine... shouldn't be using inline assembly too much anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you write in assembly gets placed verbatim in the output of the compiler.

This means that if you change the format or other global options about how to parse assembly code you will need to restore the default options at the end.

If you don't do this the code generated by the compiler after your part will become invalid.

Comment: you mean, he needs to switch back from intel noprefix format to AT&T ?

Comment: I think he means use the last line as `asm(".att_syntax prefix");`

Comment: @mangusta: exactly. May be a better option if you have large parts of assembly code is to assemble a separate module instead and just link it with the rest of the code.